# hours, minutes, seconds, knockout countdown timer

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

Hi I was wondering if anyone could show me how to make a knockout countdown timer that shows hours, minutes, and seconds

[need a knockout timer for the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453362/need-a-knockout-timer-for-the-project)

Jeroen's answer with the fiddle is awesome but it only shows seconds. Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a couple of computed observables.

**HTML**

```
<div id="timer">
    <span data-bind="text: hours"></span> hrs
    <span data-bind="text: minutes"></span> minutes
    <span data-bind="text: seconds"></span> seconds
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.timer = ko.observable(4566);

    self.hours = ko.computed( function() {
        return Math.floor(self.timer() / 3600);
    }, self);

    self.minutes = ko.computed( function() {
        return Math.floor(self.timer() / 60) % 60;
    }, self);

    self.seconds = ko.computed( function() {
        return self.timer() % 60;
    }, self);


    setInterval(function() {
        var newTimer = self.timer() -1;
        self.timer(newTimer <= 0 ? 60 : newTimer);
    }, 1000);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```