# knockoutjs : multiple countdown timers in list (foreach)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, timer

I found an existing countdown timer example here on stackoverflow : 
[solution by @Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453362/need-a-knockout-timer-for-the-project)

This is using a single timer on a single ko.observable(num).

I need to implement this in a foreach context (list)...
the list is a ko.observableArray(), and i'm not sure how i can do the following :

1) Make the property myObservableList.DeliveryTime observable on the fly

2) Create a function which takes the value (hh:mm) as parameter, and returns/init's the countdown timer

**See the included snippet :**

```js
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
        
    self.timer = ko.observable(60);
     
    setInterval(function() {
        var newTimer = self.timer() - 1;
        self.timer(newTimer <= 0 ? 60 : newTimer);
    }, 1000);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="timer"> <span data-bind="text: timer"></span> </div>
```

Comment: What happens when you try the custom `timer` binding you've linked, inside `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do? Each timer model has it's own set interval method. I just created a list/array of timers. Then I use the map function to iterate through each piece of data and return a new TimerModel back to the Timers array in the ViewModel.

```js
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var timers = [60,30,10,60]
    this.TimeAmount = ko.observable();
    this.Timers = ko.observableArray(timers.map(function(timer){
      return new TimerModel(timer);
    }));
    this.AddTimer = function() {
      if(self.TimeAmount()) {
        self.Timers.push(new TimerModel(self.TimeAmount()));
      }
      self.TimeAmount(null)
    }
};

var TimerModel = function(time) {
  var self = this;
  this.Timer = ko.observable(time);
  
  setInterval(function() {
        var newTimer = self.Timer() - 1;
        if(newTimer <= 0) {
          self.Timer(0) }
        else {
          self.Timer(newTimer <= 0 ? 60 : newTimer);
        }
    }, 1000);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: TimeAmount" />
<button data-bind="click: AddTimer">Add Timer</button>
<div id="timer" data-bind="foreach: Timers">
  <span data-bind="text: Timer"></span>
</div>
```